# How can gevent.sleep() be canceled?

Tags: python, gevent

I have a greenlet that does some I/O and figures out how long to sleep until it should be awakened to continue. Say some external event should cause the sleeping greenlet to immediately awaken and continue after the sleep. How can I achieve this?

A solution is killing the greenlet and creating a new one but that seems, well, messy. Another solution I've tried is `gevent.wait` with a timeout of 0, 0.1, etc. This didn't do anything at all and also seems messy.

```py
import gevent
import gevent.monkey
gevent.monkey.patch_all()

import time

class G(gevent.Greenlet):
  def _run(self):
    t = self._determine_how_long_to_sleep()
    print(f'in run, will sleep for {t}s')

    start = time.time()

    # how do I make this cancel-able?
    gevent.sleep(t)

    end = time.time()

    # should get here within 1s of canceling the sleep
    assert end - start < t + 1
    print('success')

  def _determine_how_long_to_sleep(self):
    "it's not important how we get this number or why"
    return 5

g = G()
g.start()

gevent.sleep(1)

# Sure, this works, but not ideal.
g.kill()
g = G()
g.start()

# Does nothing whatsoever:
#gevent.wait(objects=[g], timeout=0.2)

g.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to notice that gevent.Greenlet subclasses greenlet.greenlet which has a `throw` method that can be caught:

```py
import gevent.monkey
gevent.monkey.patch_all()
import gevent
import time

class InterruptedException(Exception):
    pass

class G(gevent.Greenlet):
  def _run(self):
    t = 5
    start = time.time()
    try: gevent.sleep(t)
    except InterruptedException: pass
    end = time.time()
    print(f'slept for ~{end-start}s')
    assert end - start < t + 1

g = G()
g.start()

gevent.sleep(0)

try:
    g.throw(InterruptedException)
except gevent.exceptions.LoopExit:
    # There are no other greenlets to switch to so we get this error.
    pass
```

The gevent docs say to avoid using greenlet.throw and prefer higher level abstractions like gevent.event.Event. In my case, having a sleep that can be canceled can be accomplished by this method. Move the logic for knowing you have to cancel the greenlet to calling `set` on a gevent.event.Event. OK!

```py
import gevent.monkey
gevent.monkey.patch_all()
import gevent
import gevent.event
import time

ev = gevent.event.Event()

class InterruptedException(Exception):
    pass

class G(gevent.Greenlet):
  def _run(self):
    print('will wait for event')
    ev.wait()
    print('done waiting for event')

g = G()
g.start()

gevent.sleep(2)
ev.set()
print('after event set')
```